# can't create foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE share(
    `User_1` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `User_2` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`User_1`,`User_2`),
     CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`User_1`) REFERENCES user(`Dev_ID`)  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE ,
     CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`User_2`) REFERENCES user(`Dev_ID`)  ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE 
);
```

I get this error:

> {Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed }

I want to make a link between user1 and user2.

Comment: Where do you get that error? That isn't formatted like a MySQL error at all. Besides, there is nothing wrong with your syntax. You query should succeed.

Comment: I concur; your syntax looks correct, so it's probably how it's being applied. Try a much simpler constraint (say, one foreign key, with no restricts), and see if you get the same error. Then build up from there until you find what triggers it. Also, you can try this sql directly against the database you're using to see if it works.

Comment: verify that the `Dev_ID` field in the user table is also a varchar(50). Foreign key fields MUST have identical defitions as well.

Comment: Can you post your create SQL for the user table?

Comment: i fixed it.user table has charset=utf8.i just change share to utf8 too