# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed?

Tags: mysql

I got this error when create table: `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`?

```
create table comment(
Comment_ID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
User_1 varchar(50) not null,
Note_ID int(11) UNSIGNED not null,
PRIMARY key(Comment_ID),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`User_1`) REFERENCES `user` (`Dev_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`User_2`) REFERENCES `user` (`Dev_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`Note_ID`) REFERENCES `note`(`Note_ID`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

it's OK when I remove `fk_3`.

This my note table

```
CREATE TABLE `note` (
 `Dev_ID` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Note_ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `Time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Mood` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Body` varchar(3000) NOT NULL,
  `Visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `Share` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Update` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Dev_ID`,`Note_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_note_user` FOREIGN KEY (`Dev_ID`)
                       REFERENCES `user` (`Dev_ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [can't create foreign key constraint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076921/cant-create-foreign-key-constraint)

Comment: Don't re-ask the same question. You can modify your previous question to add the new information.

Answer (score 25):

That's because the primary key of the `note` table is `(Dev_ID,Note_ID)` but you are only referencing one of those columns (`Note_ID`) in your constraint.

A FK constraint must always consist of all PK columns.

Comment: Or all Unique. If he creates a `UNIQUE KEY (Note_ID)` on table `Note`, the FK will work fine.

Comment: i change comment table to
{
create table comment(
Comment_ID int UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT not null,
Owner varchar(50) not null,
Note_ID int(11) UNSIGNED not null,
Commenter varchar(50) not null,
PRIMARY key(Comment_ID),
CONSTRAINT `fk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Owner`,`Note_ID`) REFERENCES `note`(`Dev_ID`,`Note_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Commenter`)REFERENCES `user`(`Dev_ID`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
}
And i got "Duplicate key on write or update"

Comment: @user1235872: "duplicate key" means you are inserting the same values twice for the primary key.

Comment: This answere just gave me the right hint for my case. I was using only one column but had two set as a Key. THX and +1 from here :D

Answer (score 12):

Also make sure that both tables are innoDB.

Comment: @you'r welcome. MySql sometime become crazy in showing usfull error messages.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answers that have been given, you would also get this error if the field types did not match. For example, if you tried to create a foreign key constraint between a `varchar` field and an `int` field.

Comment: In addition, this can be very sneaky! `INT(10)` is not the same as `INT(11)` and the signing of the values also matters. They need to be identical. MySQL is amazing at giving garbage error messages and this is not fixed in MariaDB either.

Comment: This happened for me because the target column was `int(11) unsigned` and the source column just `int(11)

Answer (score 3):

This problem occur because the column

```
`Note_ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Is neither primary nor unique.

Just make it

```
`Note_ID` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL UNIQUE
```

And it will work.

Answer (score 2):

One more addition: charsets of the fields must match.

In the referenced table I had ascii as a  default charset: `DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii` was reported by `show create table`. I tried to create the referencing table with `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf` and I got 'Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed'.

After I changed this to `DEFAULT CHARSET=ascii` on the new table (the referencing one), it was created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure the collation is the same on both fields.  I had the same problem when one was `latin-general-ci` and the other was `utf8_unicode_ci`.  Not sure why the collation changed on the one table but fixing this resolved the issue.