# Foreign Key Constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: mysql

There are several other questions about this topic that I have gone through, but I can't seem to figure out how their solutions apply to my tables. Check out the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fab1). You can see it builds the schema just fine.

Basically, one table is a table of contacts/people. The second table is a table of countries. I am attempting to create a foreign key reference between `contacts.country_id` and `countries.id`.

Now, add the following to the panel on the left side:

```
ALTER TABLE `ultra_contacts`
ADD INDEX `fk_test` (`country_id`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_test` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `ultra_countries` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE`
```

The alter table code is not working for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

The error is: `Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_e342e.#sql-7711_1a4d2' (errno: 150):` Using a 3rd party program (HeidiSQL) the error is a bit more detailed:

`Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434518/mysql-foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed-error

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078111/foreign-key-constraint-is-incorrectly-formed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10076921/cant-create-foreign-key-constraint  (not saying these are dupes, just related)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use foreign keys on a MyISAM table, which is not allowed (they only work with InnoDB).  Take a look here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64951 All I've changed from your original is the table type (from MyISAM to InnoDB) and then I added the constraint.  Worked fine.

Full disclosure - I'm the author of SQL Fiddle :)

Comment: Ah yeah I knew it had to be InnoDB... not sure how I missed that. Thanks! And great site as well! I use it a lot for quick testing. Keep it up!